# Django require user when creating password, don't require when editing

Tags: django, django-forms

my ModelForm definition looks like this:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

So password is required when I'm creating a new user. However I'd like to NOT require it when editing the user. My edit/add is handled in views.py in the following way

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            messages.success(request, "User '%s' created" % new_user.username)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'user/add.html', {"form": form})

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def edit(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if f.is_valid():
            f.save()
            messages.success(request, "User '%s' altered" % user.username)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user')
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=user)
        return render(request, 'user/edit.html', {"form": form, "user": user})
```

Thanks for the answer.

Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_edit = kwargs.get('is_edit', False)
        if 'is_edit' in kwargs:
            del kwargs['is_edit']
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_edit:
            self.fields['password'].required = False
```

Then, in your edit() function:

```
f = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user, is_edit=True)
```

I use this type of thing fairly regularly in our codebase.

Comment: Thank you, I've just started with Python/Django and this taught me a lot

Comment: Thank you for adding that "in" check to my answer.